# C++ reading a sequence of integers

Tags: c++

gooday programers. I have to design a C++ program that reads a sequence of positive integer values that ends with zero and find the length of the longest increasing subsequence in the given sequence. For example,  for the following 
sequence of integer numbers:

```
1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 1 2 5 6 8 9 1 2 3 0
```

the program should return 6 
i have written my code which seems correct but for some reason is always returning zero, could someone please help me with this problem.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    int x = 1;          // note x is initialised as one so it can enter the while loop
    int y = 0; 
    int n = 0;

    while (x != 0)          // users can enter a zero at end of input to say they have entered all their numbers
    { 
        cout << "Enter sequence of numbers(0 to end): ";
        cin >> x; 
        if (x == (y + 1))   // <<<<< i think for some reason this if statement if never happening 
        { 
            n = n + 1;
            y = x;
        } 
        else 
        {
            n = 0;
        }
    } 
    cout << "longest sequence is: " << n << endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Please edit your code to remove all the extraneous vertical white space, which is making it currently unreadable.

Comment: There are many ways to track down the problem. One would be to use a debugger.

Comment: In fact, debugging is one of the important skills to learn for programmers, and one starts on programs like this.

Comment: if you don't have valid precondition for your loop, why do you use `while`? You should use `do {} while` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your program, you have made some assumptions, you need to validate them first.

1. That the subsequence *always* starts at 1
2. That the subsequence *always* increments by 1

If those are correct assumptions, then here are some tweaks

1. Move the `cout` outside of the loop
2. The canonical way in C++ of testing whether an input operation from a stream has worked, is simply test the stream in operation, i.e. `if (cin >> x) {...}`
3. Given the above, you can re-write your `while` loop to read in `x` and test that `x != 0`
4. If both above conditions hold, enter the loop
5. Now given the above assumptions, your first check is correct, however in the event the check fails, remember that the new subsequence starts at the current input number (value `x`), so there is no sense is setting `n` to `0`.
6. *Either way*, `y` must *always* be current value of `x`.

If you make the above logic changes to your code, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

In the last loop, your `n=0` is execute before `x != 0` is check, so it'll always return n = 0. This should work.

```
if(x == 0) {
    break;
} else if (x > y ) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is wrong logically:

```
if (x == (y + 1))   // <<<<< i think for some reason this if statement if never happening 
    {
```

Should be

```
if(x >= (y+1))
{
```

Comment: `x >= y`? Increasing need not be *at least `y+2`... I think, I have not reviewed the whole code.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas - yeah correct. Should be >= y+1 which means that also >y should work.

Comment: That wont solve the issue. The problem is the last number read, 0.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to reset your `y` variable when you come to the end of a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a list of *increasing* numbers, then your "if" condition is only testing that `x` is equal to *one more* than `y`. Change the condition to:

```
if (x > y) {
```

and you should have more luck.

Comment: this is would also count equal numbers... He was the count of sequentially increasing numbers.

Comment: That wont solve the issue. The problem is the last number read, 0, makes that n=0 always be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You always return 0, because the last number that you read and process is 0 and, of course, never make `x == (y + 1)` comes true, so the last statement that its always executed before exiting the loop its `n=0`

Hope helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are more than one problem, the first and most important that you might have not understood the problem correctly. By the common definition of *[longest increasing subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence)*, the result to that input would not be 6 but rather 8.

The problem is much more complex than the simple loop you are trying to implement and it is usually tackled with [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) techniques.

On your particular code, you are trying to count in the `if` the length of the sequence for which each element is exactly the successor of the last read element. **But** if the next element is not in the sequence you reset the length to 0 (`else { n = 0; }`), which is what is giving your result. You should be keeping a `max` value that never gets reset back to 0, something like adding in the `if` block: `max = std::max( max, n );` (or in pure C: `max = (n > max? n : max );`. Then the result will be that `max` value.